# GCC thinks that an infinite loop terminates?

Tags: c, gcc, infinite-loop, noreturn

Why is the commented line below required when compiling with `-Wall`?

```
static int H()
{
  while (1);
  __builtin_unreachable(); // Why do I need this line?
}

int main()
{
  H();
}
```

Without the `__builtin_unreachable()`, gcc 5.4.0 on linux x86 produces the following warning:

```
warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

Why does gcc not realize that the infinite loop in `H()` does not terminate?

Comment: It does realise that the loop never terminates. It probably wants to know that you realise that. After all, you declared `H` as returning an `int`, although it's obvious that `H` never returns anything and should be declared as `static void H() { …}`.

Comment: That a function never terminates has nothing to do with the warning. `no return statement in function returning non-void` the warning is still valid after `__builtin_unreachable()`. There is no return statement in the function, the warning is not that the function never returns.

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you explain why this is a warning? The int return type might come from an API and I have to match a function pointer type. Furthermore, I can't just add a `noreturn` attribute in this case; the [GNU manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) says "It does not make sense for a noreturn function to have a return type other than void." So what is gcc's objection to the code then?

Comment: @rici Are you saying that functions that don't return must have a `void` return type? That would mean (for example) that one can't use `pthread_create` to start a thread that runs until the process terminates, since the run proc doesn't return `void` (it returns `void*`). I find it hard to believe that it was the `pthread` library's intention to have such a restriction.

Comment: @KamilCuk And unfortunately the manual doesn't elaborate on why `noreturn` "doesn't make sense" with a non-void return type. Maybe they were thinking only about how `noreturn` affects the caller, not about its benefits in addressing this warning for code *inside* the function? So the manual could be partly wrong?

Comment: @personal_cloud: no, I'm not saying that. What I'm saying is that there is some reason to suspect that something is unintended when a function which has a declared return type cannot ever return. You received a warning, not an error; most warnings are for things which are legal but possibly unintended (like assignments as condition expressions, to tak a classic example), and most such warnings will be suppressed if you take some action to document that it was intentional, which is also useful for anyone reading your code.

Comment: Although, actually, looking at it again, I think Kamil is right: the warning is not that the function never returns; it's that it might return without providing a return value. (Although that happens to be impossible, that might be the result of a programming error.) Note that falling off the end of a function is only UB if the caller attempts to use the value; if the end if the function is unreachable, that can't happen.